# Why exactly is `Rc` thread unsafe?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm reading [chapter 16 — Shared-State Concurrency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html) of *The Rust Programming Language*. It says:

> Unfortunately, `Rc<T>` is not safe to share across threads. When `Rc<T>`
> manages the reference count, it adds to the count for each call to
> clone and subtracts from the count when each clone is dropped. But it
> doesn’t use any concurrency primitives to make sure that changes to
> the count can’t be interrupted by another thread.

What does it mean by

> to make sure that changes to
> the count can’t be interrupted by another thread.

The only scenario where I think the changes to count are interrupted are if a thread is created, and somehow it panics/crashes, so the locker is never unlocked so the reference count never decreases. I can imagine Rust calling the destructors of every object in scope if a panic happens.

Can somebody clarify this for me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> to make sure that changes to the count can’t be interrupted by another thread.

That's a very unfortunate phrasing, and is inaccurate. Interruptions are the least of our worries, really.

As far as concurrency is concerned, Rust's memory model is based on the memory model that C11 and C++11 adopted. If you want to learn more about memory models, I only recommend reading Preshing's article on [Weak vs Strong memory models](https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/); I'll try to do the material justice in this answer.

#### What is a memory model, you ask?

Roughly speaking, a memory model is a model which specifies which operations can be reordered, and which cannot.

The reordering may occur:

- In the optimizer.
- In the CPU.

In general, for performance reasons, reordering reads/writes is *good*. It allows more efficient utilization of the CPU and faster progress. However, the correctness of some algorithms depend on various threads observing events in a certain order... and thus sometimes some reads/writes should not be reordered. The memory model, and the memory orderings, are used to specify the exact constraints that the compiler and CPU should respect to correctly execute the algorithm.

#### How could the CPU wreck `Rc`?

By ignoring increments.

In a weak memory model, if two different cores increment the counter, one of the increment may be ignored.

Imagine the following timeline, on a given thread, where CN means that the current count of owners is N, and C0 implies destruction.

```
 T1 -- Create: C1 --- Clone: C2 -- Drop Clone: C1 --- Drop: C0.
```

Now, imagine that this thread shares `Rc`:

```
 T1 -- Create: C1 --- Clone: C2 ---------------C1---- Drop Clone: C0 --- Access **BOOM**.
                  \                                 /
 T2                \_ Clone: C2 -- Drop Clone: C1 _/
                              ^                 ^
    Only one increment was seen                 But both decrements are
```

#### Why would a CPU do that?

Performance.

A strong memory model means a lot of unnecessary chatter between cores to synchronize cache lines -- chatter which adds latency to operations.

Weaker memory models allow less chatter, and thus less latency, meaning that programs can be executed faster or for less power.

#### And if the memory model is strong enough?

Even on an hypothetical CPU where every read/write touches memory, it could still go wrong due to race conditions.

Specifically:

- T1 reads count (1), T1 computes incremented count 2, T1 writes count (2).
- T2 reads count (1), T2 computes incremented count 2, T2 writes count (2).

If you look at the `AtomicXXX` types in Rust you'll notice the presence of a number of RMW (Read-Modify-Write) operations such as `fetch_add` which *atomically* read, increment, and write.

The atomicity is important, as otherwise race conditions may occur.

#### How could the optimizer wreak `Rc`?

Even on an hypothetical CPU without any registers, where the increment/decrement would directly modify memory atomically, things could still go wrong.

The optimizer is allowed to assume that no other thread of execution is observing the writes to memory in the absence of memory ordering: doing so is Undefined Behavior, after all.

Therefore, an optimizer would be perfectly allowed to:

1. Create a clone of `Rc`.
2. Drop the original.
3. Decrement the counter (-2) -- fused decrements for fun & profit!
4. Use the clone.
5. Increment the counter (+1).
6. Drop the clone.

If another thread drops the last other reference between (3) and (5), the counter will reach 0, the other thread will therefore drop the value inside.

#### I am not sure I understand...

Don't worry, you don't *have* to!

The Rust compiler has your back. Unless you whip out `unsafe`, it will ensure that you do not accidentally introduce such race conditions.

As for understanding all that, there's a lot of literature out there. The exact effects of the ordering are [documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/enum.Ordering.html), and for the bigger picture Preshing's really good, I heartily recommend their blog.